# How to dynamically populate Android spinner with text + image

Tags: android, image, dynamic, spinner

**This is what i am trying to achieve**                  **I am able to achieve this much:**

[image: screenshot]             [image]

---

I was able to add text and image to a Spinner, but the images are not showing up in the drop-down menu next to the text. Its only shows up for the selected item of the spinner.

Here is my code:

**spinner_layout.xml**
The layout containing the main Spinner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/mySpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**spinner_value_layout.xml**
The layout for the elements in the Spinner. This will be inflated using an Adapter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinnerTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/spinnerImages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>"

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

**SpinnerActivity.java**

```
package com.example.spinner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.tempspinner.R;

public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity {

    String[] textArray = { "clouds", "mark", "techcrunch", "times" };
    Integer[] imageArray = { R.drawable.clouds, R.drawable.mark,
            R.drawable.techcrunch, R.drawable.times };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.spinner_layout);

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTextView);
        ImageView imageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinnerImages);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);

        SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_value_layout, textArray, imageArray);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

**SpinnerAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.spinner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.tempspinner.R;

public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context ctx;
    private String[] contentArray;
    private Integer[] imageArray;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects,
            Integer[] imageArray) {
        super(context,  R.layout.spinner_value_layout, R.id.spinnerTextView, objects);
        this.ctx = context;
        this.contentArray = objects;
        this.imageArray = imageArray;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_value_layout, null);

        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTextView);
        textView.setText(contentArray[position]);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerImages);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for this question, help me alot!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this..

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context ctx;
    private String[] contentArray;
    private Integer[] imageArray;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects,
            Integer[] imageArray) {
        super(context,  R.layout.spinner_value_layout, R.id.spinnerTextView, objects);
        this.ctx = context;
        this.contentArray = objects;
        this.imageArray = imageArray;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_value_layout, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTextView);
        textView.setText(contentArray[position]);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.spinnerImages);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);

        return row;    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Cool, it worked :) Can you also give a small explanation for this.

Comment: @AshAsh  You have created view only for selected item not for DropDownView. I added that view that displayed

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, getDropDownView(), getView() never get called for some reason in my scenario, so getCustomView() never gets called. Any idea why? thanks.

Comment: Quick update, I resolved my issue described above. Sample works very well - thanks for posting :)

Comment: I wish I could up-vote your answer more than once. I have been beating my head against the wall over this exact same problem for a week now. I am using a custom `SimpleCurosrAdapter` instead of an `ArrayAdapter`, but your method worked for my case as well. Thanks again, and have a great day!

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but did you realize you were requiring a resource parameter and then hardcoding it on the next line?

Answer (score 4):

## Try this

> This is the simplest way of creating a spinner with text and images both.

1. Create a new layout inside **res/layout/** with any name e.g. **spinner_value_layout.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <TableRow
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/spinnerTextView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>
       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/spinnerImages"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>"
   </TableRow>
   ```
2. Create a new class **SimpleImageArrayAdapter**

   ```
    public class SimpleImageArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
    private Integer[] images;
    private String[] text;
    private Context context;

    public SimpleImageArrayAdapter(Context context, Integer[] images,String[] text) {
      super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, images);
      this.images = images;
      this.text=text;
      this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       return getImageForPosition(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getImageForPosition(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    private View getImageForPosition(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_value_layout, parent, false);
       TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTextView);
       textView.setText(text[position]);
       ImageView imageView = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.spinnerImages);
       imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
       return row;
      }
   ```
3. and finally use this at your class where you are passing id of spinner

   ```
    Integer[] integers=new Integer[]{R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background};
    String[] strings=new String[]{"foreground","background"};
   SimpleImageArrayAdapter adapter = new 
   SimpleImageArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),integers,strings);
     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```

**Output:-**[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Spinner row.xml** You can remove my unnecessary drawable styles and images

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_img"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity layout act_add_new_prog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin_frag_four_kategori"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/aw_shadow"
        android:entries="@array/workouts"
        android:gravity="center|top|start"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Selam" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity Class**

```
package com.sam.livehealty.addprogspinner;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import com.sam.livehealty.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class AddNewProgramAct extends Activity {

    private ImageView img_back;
    private Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_add_new_prog);
        img_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_act_add_new_program_back);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_frag_four_kategori);
        spinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_row, getAllList()));

    }

    public ArrayList<ListItemAddProg> getAllList() {
        ArrayList<ListItemAddProg> allList = new ArrayList<ListItemAddProg>();
        ListItemAddProg item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Brench Presses", R.drawable.ic_circling);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Incline Presses", R.drawable.ic_diamond);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Decline Presses", R.drawable.ic_personal);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Close-Grip Bench Presses", R.drawable.ic_team);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Dumbble Flys", R.drawable.ic_wrestling);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Incle Dumbbell Flys", R.drawable.ic_team);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Parallel Bar Dips", R.drawable.ic_personal);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Dumbble Flys", R.drawable.ic_circling);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Incline Dumbble Flys", R.drawable.ic_team);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Parallel Bar Dips", R.drawable.ic_circling);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Barbell Pullovers", R.drawable.ic_wrestling);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Peck  Deck Flyes", R.drawable.ic_team);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Peck  Deck Flyes", R.drawable.ic_personal);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData(" Incline Dumbbell  Presses", R.drawable.ic_circling);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Cable Crossover Flyes", R.drawable.ic_wrestling);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Machine Bench Press", R.drawable.ic_team);
        allList.add(item);
        item = new ListItemAddProg();
        item.setData("Push-Ups", R.drawable.ic_personal);
        allList.add(item);

       /* for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            item = new ListItemAddProg();
            item.setData("Google " + i + i, R.drawable.ic_remove);
            allList.add(item);
        }*/

        return allList;
    }
}
```

**ItemModel for every row**

```
public class ListItemAddProg {
    String name;
    int logo;
    public void setData(String name, int logo) {
        this.name = name;
        this.logo = logo;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getLogo() {
        return logo;
    }
    public void setLogo(int logo) {
        this.logo = logo;
    }
}
```

**And Adapter Class**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.sam.livehealty.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItemAddProg> {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<ListItemAddProg> objects;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ListItemAddProg> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ListItemAddProg listItemAddProg = objects.get(position);
        View row = convertView;
        if (null == row) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, parent, false);
            holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_name);
            holder.img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_img);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        holder.name.setText(listItemAddProg.getName());
        holder.img.setBackgroundResource(listItemAddProg.getLogo());
        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        ImageView img;
    }
}
```