# Why my text Does not appear with the image view in spinner?

Tags: java, android, textview, spinner

[image]My text does not appear with the image view i dont know anyone who can correct me. 
Following code is the main java activity code i am trying to add a text view as well which is not working
Mainactivity.java

```
 package com.example.xainshah.spinner;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    String countryNames[]={"pakistan","india","Bangladesh","Sri Lanka"};
    int flags[]={R.drawable.pak,R.drawable.ind,R.drawable.ban,R.drawable.sri};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),flags,countryNames);
        spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

customer adapter class code is

CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.example.xainshah.spinner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Xain Shah on 4/22/2017.
 */

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context context;
    int flags[];
    String countryNames[];
    LayoutInflater Inflater;
    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationcontext,int flags[],String countryNames[] ){
        this.context=applicationcontext;
        this.flags=flags;
        this.countryNames=countryNames;
        Inflater=(LayoutInflater.from(applicationcontext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return flags.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView=Inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_layout,null);
        ImageView icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView names=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        icon.setImageResource(flags[position]);
        names.setText(countryNames[position]);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

spinner_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please add screenshot of you output

Comment: post your spinner layout...

Comment: You will get your answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422236/how-to-dynamically-populate-android-spinner-with-text-image

Comment: I getItem() function you are returning null ,it should be countryNames[position].

Comment: added screen shot @GhanshyamSharma

Comment: Displayed spinner Layout @rafsanahmad007

Comment: @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return countryNames[position];
    }
tried this as well but same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
  public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private final Activity context;
        private final String[] countryNames;
        private final Integer[] imgid;

        public CustomAdapter(Activity context, Integer flags[],String countryNames[]) {
            super(context, R.layout.spinner_layout, countryNames);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            this.context=context;
            this.countryNames =countryNames;
            this.imgid=flags;
        }

        public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_layout, null,true);

            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            txtTitle.setText(countryNames[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
            return rowView;

        }
        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
            return getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return String.valueOf(countryNames.toString());
        }
 }
```

call it using:

```
CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,flags,countryNames);
```

For layout use:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:text="FDFDFDFD"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but it;s showing ok in my code..pls copy the edited code and clean build

Comment: well it worked but when i touch on app to show drop down list it crashes

Comment: actually i use my phone as emulator so no i cant

Comment: you can...plug the phone in android studio..and enable usb debugging...

Comment: yes i run the app on my cell phone i have enabled that option but how do i get crash log from my phone to android studio

Comment: it is visible in `Android Monitor`..at the bottom tab of android studio..

Comment: uploaded logcat pic

Comment: add this in constructor...in cusotm adapter: `super(context, R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.textView2 ,countryNames);`..

Comment: @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return String.valueOf(countryNames.toString());
    }
well i changed this function in it started showing the dropdown list but it contains [Ljava.lang.string;@59ef4fe  etc i upload the pic

Comment: i cannot do chat my reputation is 18 atleast 30 is required for chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142373/discussion-between-fun-unlimited-and-rafsanahmad007).