# How to set Only country flag On Spinner

Tags: android

I implement a spinner with country name and flag using Array Adapter. But when i select the item it set both values on spinner i.e Name and flag, but I want to set only Flag on spinner look like 
[image]

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422236/how-to-dynamically-populate-android-spinner-with-text-image

Comment: Do you have any coding done already? Or just that image?

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422236/how-to-dynamically-populate-android-spinner-with-text-image#24422359) of the question, @GursewakSingh referred to, you need to create a **custom adapter** and implement [`getView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) and [`getDropdownView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getDropDownView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) to return different views.

For your case, you will want `getView()` to return a view that just shows the flag image, and `getDropdownView()` to return a view that shows the flag and the name of the country.

The spinner view will use `getView()` to show the spinner's normal view and `getDropdownView()` to render the items of the dropdown list.

Comment: thanks for answer but can you please give me example code, I want to display only image on spinner

Answer (score 1):

Use this hopefully its work fine

```
// array of data icons from source
   private static Integer[] imageIcons = { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, 
 R.drawable.c };

 // call adapter from main class
    SimpleImageArrayAdapter adapter = new SimpleImageArrayAdapter(context, imageIcons );
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

// adapter class 
  public class SimpleImageArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
    private Integer[] images;

    SimpleImageArrayAdapter(Context context, Integer[] images) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, images);
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getImageForPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getImageForPosition(position);
    }

    private View getImageForPosition(int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(images[position]);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have 2 lists one for name and one for country flag

Comment: follow same procedure use string array  with country name.  use another adapter