# ArrayAdapter not active in spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

i try to use spinner with array adapter and it will be stopped without any error can any one tell me the error in the code
i need to Appear image with text
i tried it by custom adapter and show same result 
any one help me please i am new in android application developer

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown">


    </Spinner>
</RelativeLayout>
```

spinner_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/i1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="Orange"

        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main.java

```
package com.safaa.user.spinner;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 String[] names={"apple","panana","orange"};
 int[]images={R.drawable.image,R.drawable.image3,R.drawable.image2

 };
 CustomAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner spinner=findViewById(R.id.spinner);
     adapter=new CustomAdapter(this,names,images);
     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
     spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),names[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

         @Override
         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

         }
     });

    }
}
```

CustomAdapter

```
package com.safaa.user.spinner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
Context context;
String []names;
int image[];

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[]names,int[]image) {
        super(context, R.layout.spinner_item,names);
        this.image=image;
        this.names=names;
        this.context=context;


    }
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View row =inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item,null);

        TextView t1=row.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        ImageView i1=row.findViewById(R.id.i1);

        t1.setText(names[position]);
        i1.setImageResource(image[position]);

        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row =inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item,null);

        TextView t1=row.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        ImageView i1=row.findViewById(R.id.i1);

        t1.setText(names[position]);
        i1.setImageResource(image[position]);

        return row;



    }


}
```

Comment: try to display text first without image if ok then the problem in image...be sure of the image inside drawable ...and post the error logs

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24422359/9130109

Comment: thank you it solved ,image inside drawable but the size  very large

Comment: the problem was the size of images??@Safaa Omar

Comment: yes! it was 1024x1024 pix,then i minimize the size to 225x225 on the same code

Comment: wired..but it solved